# Android Notification to the End user

Tags: android, android-notifications

App is already published on playstore, can anyone explain the proper way or channel to create and send notification to the end user? Where i can also get the info regarding how much device has received the notification and how much user have clicked on the notification and checked it?

Comment: you need to update the app

Comment: Use a 3rd party push notification provider. You still need to update your app though. Check https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-third-party-company-to-send-push-notifications-on-your-Android-iOS-apps.

Comment: i can update the app, tht's not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Implement GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) in your app and end users should install your updated app (with GCM)**

**“Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their Android applications on Android devices”.** Using this service you can send data to your application whenever new data is available instead of making requests to server in timely fashion. Integrating `GCM` in your android application enhances user experience and saves lot of battery power.
    --https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

`GCM` tutorial available in this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).

Happy coding :)